# Magento Multi-Step Product Configuration

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I'm currently attempting to extend the inherent Magento product view to divide the custom options belonging to a configurable product into sections loaded by ajax. The end goal is to create a step by step process guiding the user through each step of the product configuration process before they would add the product to the cart.

**Advanced Custom Product Options**

We are also utilizing Mageworx's Advanced Custom Product Options to allow for the larger customization of products.

**Simple Products Linked to Configurable**

Our current environment is set up to handle simple products as configurators for their parent configurable product. When a user navigates to the simple product, they are directed to the configurable product with the option represented by the simple product pre-selected.

**End Goal**

The hopeful endpoint would be that once a user clicks on a simple product, they would be redirected to the configurable product with a single pre-selected option depending on the simple product. The user would then be able to customize their order, or jump directly to adding it to the cart as is. The customization process would re-evaluate at each step to determine if there is a concurrent step, for example, if the user were to select to add trim, there would be an additional step to customize that trim, whereas if they opted out, the step would be skipped.

The idea is simply a product configurator within the Magento framework, something similar, in function, as to what appears below. The checkout steps being Style, Color, and Size, each which have their own page.

[image: Example]

[image]

**The Overarching Question**

I am fairly new to the development of Magento, and am wondering what the best method of attacking this problem is. I have thought of using an observer to hook into before add to cart, but I am unsure it would allow me to refresh the blocks and load in new data. My other idea was to tap into view.phtml and set up some ajax loading within the page itself, but that seemed a bit 'hacky'.

I have spent quite a while searching for examples on how some have overcome this problems, but haven't found much outside of some very vague ideas on what could work. If any one has insight onto a solution to my problem, their thoughts would be much appreciated.

**Current Approach**

So far I've tried creating a Router for a Controller to handle POST requests to change out the Product Option sidebar when a value is changed. It seems a little bit slow, however.